# ItemListener is interrupting AutoCompleteDecorator

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox with an Item Listener and AutoCompleteDecorator associated to it. For e.g. When I launch my swing application, the combo vox has following values in it : Almond, Apple, Avocado, Banana, Berries. When I type A in the combo box. It selects the value Almond and performs the operation defined in its Item Listener. Doesn't waits for me to type the next letter. I need both the functionalities of listener and decorator at the same time. 
Please help.

Comment: Consider using a `ActionListener` instead or using a Swing `Timer` to inject an artificial delay between `ItemListener` events